# Tcl Tk treeview with checkbuttons

Tags: treeview, tcl, tk-toolkit

Is is possible to add check button to ttk::treeview column.

Specifically I am trying to create a checklist for the user to hide or show items on the canvas when the checkbox is selected or deselected. Since there are a lot of canvas items with specific type and sub type I need a list box kind of mechanism.

Comment: Does this checklist need to be a tree, or would a simple list do? If you need a tree, do you need all of tne features of the tree widget such as being able to collapse and expand nodes?

Comment: Yes Bryan, I need to have a collapsable tree because if it is not collapsed the height of the tree will be humnugous. I pretty much want to be a able to say a bunch of polygons ( square, rectangle, triangle ) and then each polygon has five different colors. So, it can be pretty long.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I think you're on the right UI track with a tree of checkboxes (and other things I presume? Descriptive text is good when it comes to helping users with a complex UI.) But now, the bad news.

This is not something that's really supported by the [treeview](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_treeview.htm) widget. In particular, it has no ability to embed widgets, and nor does it have much in the way of built-in support for handling events on rows. While it would be possible to hack something together — you can always add your own custom bindings, use the widget facilities provided to decode the location information, and simulate buttons through appropriate images — but it would be a lot of work and it definitely would be a hack.

My best suggestion is that you try the [tktreectrl](http://tktreectrl.sourceforge.net/) widget instead. It's an external package, but it is enormously powerful (so much so that most times people wrap it in code to tame it!) and just looking at some of the demos on that linked page makes me think it can do what you want. Alas, I've no personal experience with using it, so I can't offer detailed instructions.